# Can not set center position of window edge when using window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I use javascript method :

```js
var left = ((outerWidth / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft - 8;
var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
var param = "width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", left=" + left + ", top=" + top + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=yes,directories=no";
window.open(url, "new window", param);
```

to open a new window in center screen  position. It worked for all browser except Window Edge.

In

```
window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures])
```

top and left parameters ignored in strWindowFeatures

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: suggest you show the variable definition,`dualScreenTop` `dualScreenLeft` and so on

Comment: dualScreenTop dualScreenLeft just variable to fixed with multi screen of pc. I am sure that not relate to this issue. Seem Edge ignored strWindowFeatures of window.open.

Comment: It’s kinda cute that people still try this in this day and age ... _“It worked for all browser”_ - it will never work in mine, because I have it set to open new tabs instead of popups ...

Comment: Unfortunately, because the business requirement need it open a new window, not new tabs. And behavior of edge browsers seem strange with the others.